# Java absolute path - Mac OS X - Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, jar, executable-jar

I'm about to release an java application but I have a little problem: I've completely developed the app on Mac OS X via eclipse and I use an absolute path to refer to a directory placed in:

```
"/Users/Name/Documents/folder"
```

I used `System.getProperty"os.name"` to find out if i'm currently running on a mac or not, and if it is, I will use that folder, else I will use another folder example: `C:\Users\Name\Documents\folder`.

The problem is: I have to append to this string a name that may contain other subfolder. I know that on mac to separate folder i use `"/"` and on windows `"\"`. How can i solve that issue ? any tips ?

Comment: First of all, use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to get the user's home directory.  If you use `File`, you can use `/` all the time, Windows won't care, but Linux based OS's do. You can also use [`File.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator), which I believe uses `System.getProperty("file.separator")` and where ever possible, don't hard code them if you can ;)

Comment: so on windows will work both "C:/Users/...." and "C:\Users\...." ?

Comment: @Levenlol yes. Only the windows command line insists on using the backslash.

Comment: @Levenlol To a point.  If you use `File`, it will translate the `/` to `\` automatically. If you use `getAbsolutePath` or `getCanonicalPath` I believe they also get translated, so you can save them or pass them to external process should you need to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to have the good separator :

```
System.getProperty("file.separator")
```